# Compact set in finite dimensional NLS

Tags: normed-spaces

Does there exist a finite dimensional normed linear space where closed and bounded sets are not necessarily compact?

I know the converse is true, in fact in any metric space. But I am clueless about this one. Please help.

Comment: A vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ would do.

Comment: If the scalar field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ then the NLS is linearly homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n}$ or $\mathbb C^{n}$ and every closed and bounded set is compact.